# Configuring Webpack dev server to be able to use API routes served by Express that require authorisation via Passport

Tags: webpack, passport.js, webpack-dev-server

This is my routing structure:

- http://localhost:3000/ (Application brochure website)
- http://localhost:3000/register (Application registration)
- http://localhost:3000/login (Application login)
- http://localhost:3000/app/* (React/Redux application - using Passport auth)
- http://localhost:3000/api/* (Express API - using Passport auth)

Everything is working as it should when using the Express server and building bundle.js from the CLI, but to speed up development I want to make use of the Webpack dev server now, and now things need to be configured in a way that takes into consideration the Passport authorisation that has been set up.

Here is my Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './client/src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/server/public',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './client'//,
    // proxy: {
    //   '/api/*': {
    //     target: 'http://localhost:3000',
    //     secure: false
    //   }
    // }
  }
};
```

I have been through the Webpack docs but nothing is really clear to me, and nothing I have tried has seemed. I’m going round in circles, and am obviously missing a fundamental step as I imagine this is a pretty common use case.

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

*Edit*

From what I've beed reading, it seems an option may be to actually ditch Webpack dev server, and use webpack-hot-middleware and webpack-dev-middleware - does this sound about right?